# Creating a reactive queue or data structure using RxJava

Tags: data-structures, queue, message-queue, rx-java

I need to create a queue where when an item is added to the queue a subscriber should be notified. Only solution comes to my brain is to use a while loop to poll the queue or use peek the queue compare whether a new object is added to the queue, if new item found then use onNext() to forward the item to subscriber. It would be an endless loop and that is what I need to observe the queue.

Comment: Can you provide the implementation of the queue?

Comment: Its a requirement. The above mentioned is just a theory which can use peek() to get the item and compare it to the previous written item.

Comment: do you know about `PublishSubject`?  When you say endless loop do you imply that it is blocking? That doesn't sound like reactive style.

Comment: My requirement is to have a queue which should notify a function when ever a new item is added to the queue or a collection.

Answer (score 0):

You could sub-class one of the queues and have the `add`/`offer`/etc... methods call your `Observable`.

```
public class SubscriberQueue<E> extends LinkedList<E> {

   private Observable<E> mObservable = PublishSubscriber.create();

   @Override
   public boolean add(E e) {
      if (super.add()) {
         mObservable.onNext(e);
      }
   }

   public Observable<E> getObservable() {return mObservable;}
}

// Test code
SubscriberQueue<Integer> myQueue = new SubscriberQueue<>();
myQueue.getObservable().subscribe(i -> System.out.println("Added: " + i));
myQueue.add(1);
```

Comment: You are recommending to fire the object when ever a new object is added to the SubscriberQueue i.e, I need to first add an item to the data structure then send the item to the subscriber.

Comment: The code above doesn't achieve any thing. We have to make a function observable to subscribe to it. I don't see how it works with the above function.

Comment: OK @user64287, I filled in the missing blanks I think were tripping you up in the above example. Does that clarify things?

Comment: The code above does add the object to the data structure FIRST and then notifies the Observable SECOND.

Comment: Instead old method of continuously reading and keeping the thread to sleep is better the man compromising single responsibility principle.